# Bitbucket clone freezes on the same large file

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, tortoisehg

I have a mercurial repo setup in bitbucket.
I attempt to clone this repo using sourcetree (2.6.10.0) and https.
The clone starts fine and i can see files being copied across to my machine.
However when it attempts to clone a particular file, it comes to a stand still and errors (stream ended unexpectedly (got 449 bytes, expected 4096)).
The only difference between this file and the other files is its size (60MB).
I have tried using tortoise hg...i get the same error.

Has a limit been added to the file size that bitbucket can clone?
Is the issue with bitbucket or the clients that i've tried (sourcetree/tortoise hg)?
Any ideas of how i can get around this issue?

Comment: Probably a network issue. Try with a different network connection.

Comment: Mercurial shouldn't clone files individually, could you paste the redacted output of `hg clone --debug`. It might also be worth asking directly on the #bitbucket freenode IRC channel, they are very friendly and could help check if there is any issue on bitbucket side.

Comment: @dereli - I've tried on different networks (wired and wireless)....same issue

Comment: @BorisFeld - I'll debug and let you know

Comment: @BorisFeld - Curious development. My colleagues have tried cloning the same repo, on the same network...it works fine for them. We're all admins on the same repo. However my version of mercurial is 4.7 however my colleagues have older versions (4.6.1, 3.7.3)

Comment: @Yas could you paste a copy of `hg clone --debug` so we can debug what's wrong?